# Android studio error while building the project

Tags: android, android-studio, compiler-errors

I am trying to build a proj in android studio but its throwing the following error.
I went through many links and tried out but no  use.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

 * What went wrong:
 Execution failed for task ':comtablet:mergeDebugResources'.
   > D:\DG_Studioprojects\com.proj.tablet.ba\comitablet\src\main\res\drawable-xhdpi\ic_launcher.png: 
    Error: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 
   'C:\Users\raghav\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\20.0.0\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 42
```

Any help would be highly appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: Try building with `--stacktrace` option enabled to get more info about the error.

Answer (score 0):

download latest SDK-build-tools in sdk manager current latest is 23.0.2 and change its config in build.gradle(module) then try n sync again.

Comment: Thanks Raghav,But If I do this I am ended up with errors related to httpget in few classes.I guess in 6.0 these apis wont work or something??

Comment: can you please post your gradle file